# Measure temperature of a heater wire

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, measurements, experimental-technique

I would like to measure the temperature of a heating wire (tungsten) that's wrapped around my sample. 
Does anyone have a better idea than using a infrared thermometer, which has relatively low accuracy? 
The expected temperature will be between 200-400°C

Comment: perhaps a thermocouple

Comment: How about looking up the temperature coefficient of resistivity of tungsten and using that to get the temperature of the wire? All you would need to do is measure the voltage and the current through the wire.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I think that will get you the temperature of the wire in free air. This wire is in contact with a material and heat will transfer to the material.

Comment: @Bob D - Yes, heat will indeed transfer to the material that the wire is wrapped around, but regardless of that the increased resistivity of the wire itself will be determined by the temperature rise of the wire.

Comment: @SamuelWeir But won't that give you some kind of average temperature of the wire. Won't the surface of the wire facing away from the material be at a higher temperature than the surface in contact with the material. I guess it depends on what the OP wants, the hot spot temperature or the average temperature.

Comment: When we did motor temperature testing the preference was to use thermocouples on the coil. For those cases where the coil was not accessible, or if we wanted the temperature of armature coils, we would resort to change in resistance.

Comment: @Bob B "Won't the surface of the wire facing away from the material be at a higher temperature than the surface in contact with the material." - Well, I think that we have to assume that the temperature throughout the heating wire is fairly uniform, otherwise none of these methods like resistivity or thermocouples will work and we are just left with something like doing low-T spatially-resolved, microscopic infrared pyrometry.

Comment: @SamuelWeir 30 gauge wire was a laboratory standard to reduce effect on measured temperature. Securing the thermocouple can be tricky (high temp solder one possibility) and should be done by a qualified lab technician.  For this reason, I have deleted my answer.

Comment: @CPE Per M. Enns thermocouple method is possible but is tricky to attach and should be done by a trained technician. Also per SamuelWeir change in resistance also possible if the average temperature (not hot spot temperature) of the wire is all you need.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Just a final comment. Regarding your statement "I think that we have to assume that the temperature throughout the wire is fairly uniform" you can't always assume this because as a practical matter the degree of contact between the wire and the material will vary. I used to see a test involving nichrome heater wire wrapped around plastic specimens. You can see varying degrees of color due to variations in contact.

Comment: @BobD - Hey, Bob. Didn't mean to have you delete your answer. Was just wondering about practical things like getting good thermal contact with something as difficult to solder or weld to as tungsten. As for issues of thermal contact with the specimen, I think that the OP would have to clarify how much contact there is between the heating wire and the specimen (I was picturing something different from you), and also what the desired amount of temperature accuracy is.

Comment: @SamuelWeir No problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford it, a thermal camera (e.g., FLIR) should do the job.

It determines the temperature of objects based on their infrared radiation.

There are plenty of models with different characteristics and features - you'll have to choose (buy, rent) a model, which will be optimal for your expected applications.

It would require some tuning and calibration to take into account emissivity of the wire, temperature range, etc., but, in the end, it'll give you a lot of useful information.

Comment: @CPE Just keep in mind that for a good thermal contact, the thermocouple will likely be electrically connected with the wire, which may present an issue, if the voltage you use to heat up the wire is high and the TC device is not properly isolated.